# Loop through something 10 times, then increase a value and repeat the process for a total of 10 times?

Tags: php, loops

I need x (0) to increase with a value for 10 times, then I need to add a value to y and let x increase again from 0. 
Basically I'm creating a grid.

Right now I manually do one "row", loop 10 times through that, then manually change y, loop again, repeat. I want to automatize this.

```
$int = 0;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$z = 0;

while($int < 10) {
    echo 'posX="'. $x .'" posY="'. $y .'" posZ="'. $z .'<br>';
    $int++;
    $x+=20;
}
```

What I'd manually do now is change the value of y to 20, then let the loop run again, I have to manually change this 10 times.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. I've used variables `$x_inc` and `$y_inc` to define how much to increment `$x` and `$y` in each pass of the loop:

```
$x = $y = $z = 0;
$x_inc = 20;
$y_inc = 20;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
        echo 'posX="'. $x .'" posY="'. $y .'" posZ="'. $z .'<br>';
        $x += $x_inc;
    }
    $y += $y_inc;
    $x = 0;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YSZiT)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the modulus personally it always feels like the best way to handle these sort of "timed" increments. You can read about the modulo operator [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). This also means you dont have to have nested loops

```
$int = 11;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$z = 0;

while($int < 110) {
    echo '"posX="'. $x .'" posY="'. $y .'" posZ="'. $z .'"<br />"';
    $int ++; //you probably want to do this last unless you need int to increment before we evaluate it
    $x+=20;
    if(($int % 10) == 0) { //basically if int is a multiple of 10 you want to add to y and reset x
         $y += 10; //your value
         $x = 0; // reset x to 0 for the next 10 iterations 
    }
}
```

====== OR =======

```
$int = 0;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$z = 0;

while($int < 110) {
    echo '"posX="'. $x .'" posY="'. $y .'" posZ="'. $z .'"<br />"';
    $int ++; //you probably want to do this last unless you need int to increment before we evaluate it
    $x+=20;
    if(($int / 10) == 1) { //basically if int is a multiple of 10 you want to add to y and reset x
         $y += 10; //your value
         $x = 0; // reset x to 0 for the next 10 iterations 
    }
}
```

Comment: This would need a reset of x somehow, because right now this is what I get: https://ibb.co/YtcTTCD

Comment: Sorry I actually overlooked that in your question which changes how you need to do this. (see edits)